# SQL Server Conditional filtering

Tags: sql, sql-server, where-clause, boolean-logic

I essentially would like to execute a statement where x=1 AND a=2. If a<>2 then return results for filter x=1.

I've tried OR statement but it ignores my a=2 filter if there is a scenario where a does equal 2. Example below

```
select * 
from dbo.test
where (x=1 and a=2)
or
x=1
```

**For output purposes below: type = x and Id = a**

Expected result when Type = 1.

```
    Id(a)   Name    Person  Type(x)
    2        a       Mike    1
    7        b       Jim     1
    3        c       Tom     1
    4        d       Tim     1
    5        e       Dave    1
```

Expected result when `Type = 1` and `Id = 2`

```
    Id(a)   Name    Person  Type(x)
    2        a       Mike    1
```

Expected result when `Type = 1` and `Id <> 2` (scenario when there is no '2' in Id column)

```
    Id(a)   Name    Person  Type(x)
    8        a       Mike    1
    7        b       Jim     1
    3        c       Tom     1
    4        d       Tim     1
    5        e       Dave    1
```

The issue is not when `Id = 2`. It is returning `Type = 1` when Id <> 2. Does that mean a case statement?

Comment: And what exactly is wrong with the example you gave? Could you more clearly elaborate on what the result you're currently getting and what you would like to get?

Comment: As far as I understand it, it's logically inconsistent. If a=2, then also filter by x=1, but if a<>2, then you filter only by x=1. A little boolean algebra shows that the value of a is irrelevant, and the only filter in any case is x=1. Am I correct?

Comment: @Alejandro: Yes. And the example statement is valid SQL, so this seems to be more about basic Boolean algebra than anything.

Comment: So are you querying against multiple tables, and if there is an ID of 2 you want only ID of 2 and x of 1, but if there's no id =2 then return all records where x = 1?

Comment: Essentially yes, I am building a hierarchy based off `type` and need the results retained for `type = 1` if there is no match for `id=2`.

Answer (score 2):

```
select * 
from dbo.test
where (x=1 and a=2)
   or x=1
```

Is the same as:

```
select * 
from dbo.test
where x=1
```

`AND` requires both conditions be met, and `OR` requires one condition to be met.  The value of `a` is irrelevant.

UPDATE:
You can get what you're after using the `RANK()` function in conjunction with a `CASE` statement:

```
;WITH cte AS (SELECT *,RANK() OVER(ORDER BY CASE WHEN id = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 2 END)RNK
              FROM Table1
              WHERE Type = 1)
SELECT *
FROM cte
WHERE RNK = 1
```

If id = 2 is present in the table, only that record will be returned, otherwise all records will be returned.

Demo: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/06c91/13/0)

Comment: Correct the value of `a` is irrelevant. How would i write the statement to make it relevant while also returning x=1 if a <> 2.

Comment: How would the value of `a` be used?  You're already returning every value where `x = 1`, what would you like to have happen?

Comment: I want x=1 to be the default filter. But if A=2 return a=2. If a<>2 return x=1.

Comment: @user3597889 Sorry, I'm struggling to understand. Do you want `WHERE a=2 OR x=1`?  Do you want to `ORDER` the results giving preference to where `A=2`?  Some sample data and desired output would be helpful.

Comment: I know I am having trouble explaining it :o. So I have a query where x=1..always. Within that, when a=2 return (x=1 and a=2). If a<>2 then return default x=1.

Comment: `Id Id name Person type
2 a Mike x
1 b Jim x
4 c Tom  x
3 d Tim x
5 e Dave x`

Comment: I'm new, having trouble with the UI. I'll post better output.

Comment: @user3597889 editing your question is probably the best place to show what data you have and what you want to get, you can paste it in and then highlight it and click the `{}` icon to format it as code.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that you want to return a single row.

```
insert into test(x,a,v) values (0, 0, 'No good')
insert into test(x,a,v) values (1, 0, 'OK')
insert into test(x,a,v) values (1, 2, 'Better')
```

- You want the row that has x=1 a=2 if it is there
- You want the row that has x=1 if there is none better
- You want nothing if there is no x=1 row

If that's the case then it is a bit tricky. You can score the rows using a CASE statement and then pick the row that has the best value. This may give you more than one row back if there is a tie.

```
SELECT v
  FROM test
 WHERE CASE WHEN x=1 AND a=2 THEN 1000
            WHEN x=1 AND a<>2 THEN 100
            ELSE 0 END = 
 (SELECT MAX(CASE WHEN x=1 AND a=2 THEN 1000
                 WHEN x=1 AND a<>2 THEN 100
                 ELSE 0 END)
    FROM test)
```

Comment: There's more efficient ways to do this (for one thing, `x = 1` can be factored out into the `WHERE` clause, as it's required), but I suspect this is what the OP is trying to say they want.  Need more info, though.